# Why haven't we gone back to the moon?

Tags: the-moon, history

In 40 years why has no country sent a manned mission to the Moon?

I am aware the US retired the types of rockets that could get a man to the moon but why would they do that and why wouldn't they or any other country in the world develop a similar rocket and send someone to the Moon?

If finances are the problem, why weren't they a problem 40 years ago?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange! You might try doing some reading on the subject first. If you find something there unclear, and you are looking for a fact-based answer and not just opinions, then you can ask another question, describing what you have found out, and which points need clarification. Right now this question is not a good fit for stackexchange because an answer would have to be a history book, or just pure opinions. [Take the tour](http://space.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out more about how to ask better stackexchange questions. Have fun!

Comment: @uhoh, thanks! I thought it would be simple enough for a short_ish_ answer.

Comment: The Apollo program was a product of the cold war and fulfilled a military/geopolitical goal (despite being done by a "civilian" space program).  No one has shown that going to the moon provides any economic value -- yet.

Comment: *"Why haven't we gone back to the moon?"* Been there, done that, got the moon rocks! (But mostly 'cold war' as mentioned in previous comment by @Erik.) In addition to that, for further research, it would make more sense to send robotic probes, In the time since the moon landings, robotic technology has advanced immensely. Astronauts, not so much..